# SAP HANA | Get string between two strings

Tags: sql, hana

I have below data in my table T -

```
    ROW      Col1

      1       utm_source:|utm_medium:kiosk|device:d|expires:Sun, 02 Jun 
              2019 13:27:28 GMT|IP:10.YYY.YY.YY|
      2       IP:10.XXX.XX.XX|storeid:TL04K2|
      3       IP:10.YY.YX.XZ|
```

I need to get IP from this column which will be identified by string start as 'IP:' and string end as '|'

Is it possible to get this with substring_regexp in hana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using :

```
select substr_regexpr('IP:+(?<=IP:)(.*?)(?=\|)' in your column ) from dummy;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible and even with the `SUBSTRING_REGEXPR` function, you mentioned.

Just build the regular expression that matches the string between `IP:` and `|` and use it in the function:

```
 SELECT ROW
      , SUBSTRING_REGEXPR (' -- put your regular expression here -- ' IN "Col1") as IP_EXTRACTED
 FROM 
      T;
```

There are multiple ways to express your condition as a regex, one could be

```
IP:([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3})\|
```

This one would match only IP addresses that have 1 to 3 digits between the dots (and not any characters.

```
SELECT ROW
  , SUBSTRING_REGEXPR ('IP:([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3})\|'
                      IN "Col1" 
                      GROUP 1) as IP_EXTRACTED
FROM 
  T;
```